# How do you use tenses with the word "after" sensibly: which combos of tenses work and which do not?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, conditionals, sequence-of-tenses

No context is required, it’s just a normal question about using the word *after*. For instance, here are some easy sentences:

1. After he **finishes** his work, he **will go** for a walk.
2. After he **finished** his work, he **would eat** something.
3. After he **has finished** his work, he **went** shopping.

I’m not sure which tense I should use after the word *after*, and I thought I couldn’t use past tense as in the second example.

Comment: Did you do research to solve your problem? Did you try searching for similar questions in ELL and ELU? What did you find?

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question, which needs a long and detailed answer (which it probably won't get). Quickly: (1) is fine, (2) may not mean what you think it means—it's a habitual construction—and (3) doesn't work at all.

Comment: The third sentence would normally end as the first one did: *After he **has finished** his work, he **will go** for a walk.* The second sentence could also end as you currently have the third: *After he **finished** his work, he **went** shopping.* But there is no *single* answer.